# Error con Django Cache

Tags: python, django, cache

Estoy intentando generar una caché con Django caché. Según la configuración necesito programar algo así.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unix:/cache/memcached.sock',
    }
}
```

Después como solo quiero generar una caché a una parte de mi modelo, programo una pequeña función que genere una caché solo a mis productos.

```
def cache_productos():
    valor = cache.get('productos')
    if not valor:
        print('no debera estar entrando')
        valor = Producto.objects.all()
        cache.set('productos', valor, 3600)
    return valor
```

Esto me devuelve éste error

> module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Si elimino el `unix` de la url no crea la caché, siempre me devuelve None y me devuelve el queryset que consulta.

Comment: `module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'` , generalmente indica un intento de uso de un socket de dominio UNIX  (que es lo que ocurre en tu caso) en sistema operativo Windows.

Comment: El sistema que estoy utilizando es Windows, pero si le quito `unix:` no funciona la función `cache.set()` y no sé porque no está funcionando.